# How can i use Google Drive API from a CLI (without browser) and using OAuth2?

Tags: rest, oauth-2.0, drive

Is it possible to authenticate and get the access token only using CLI? I don't have a browser (for the OAuth2 consent part) and i need to authenticate and request resources using the REST API.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no. Google OAuth for User Credentials is performed by a web browser.

If you also have a Google Cloud account, there are ways to create OAuth Access Tokens, but these are short-lived (3600 seconds). Then there is G Suite Domain-Wide delegation that uses a Google Cloud Service Account.

I wrote an article on how to do OAuth using curl but this still requires a web browser, but you can save the tokens and use on a remote device. [link](https://www.jhanley.com/google-oauth-2-0-testing-with-curl/).